# how to disable x-mod-ps header

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd

how disable this header ? googled ,no reply;
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.9.14.6-358

I attempt:         RequestHeader unset X-Mod-Pagespeed

It's does nothing

Answer (score 0):

It's generated because mod_pagespeed for apache is installed and enabled in your apache server.
On ubuntu/debian you can disable it easily by doing:

```
"a2dismod pagespeed"
```

You can check the exact name of the module launching a2dismod without argument.
The other way is to go to your apache config folder and remove the pagespeed symlink in mods-enabled.

Don't forget to restart apache through "`/etc/init.d/apacche2 restart`".

Comment: All these methods disable pagespeed - but its probably there for a reason.

Comment: Right sir, I didn't pay attentionto the details, mea culpa

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the source code for mod_pagespeed and recompile - look for a line starting with something like.....

```
apr_table_add(request->headers_out, "X-Mod-Pagespeed"....
```

Comment: ended up just killing the header by reverse proxying nginx

Answer (score 0):

It's a response header, not a request header -- so just use Header unset not RequestHeader.